# Keras binary_crossentropy cost function systematic error with large networks

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, theano

The title may be too specific and this may also apply to other cost functions as well. Basically I have the dummy setup as below (in my case I have a vastly different architecture, but the problem is always replicated):

```
hidden_units=10000

l2_sparsity = 5e-7
l1_sparsity = 1e-8
mod=Sequential([Dense(hidden_units, input_shape = (1000,), activation="relu",  kernel_regularizer=l1_l2(l1=l1_sparsity, l2=l2_sparsity),
                    ),
                Dense(hidden_units, activation="relu",  kernel_regularizer=l1_l2(l1=l1_sparsity, l2=l2_sparsity),
                    ),
                Dense(1000, activation="sigmoid",
                        )
    ])
adam = Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0)
mod.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=adam, metrics=['binary_accuracy'])



x = np.array([np.array([random.random() for i in range(1000)], dtype=np.float64) for i in range(10)])
classes = (x + 0.5).astype(np.uint32)

def replica_cross_entropy_loss(predictions, truth):
    eps=10e-8

    predictions = np.clip(predictions, eps, 1.0-eps)
    x = np.log(1.0 *predictions / (1.0 - predictions) )

    return np.mean(np.clip(x, 0, None) - x * truth + np.log(1 + np.exp(-abs(x))))

mod.fit(x[:2],classes[:2], batch_size=128, epochs=1)



preds = mod.predict(x[:2])
print replica_cross_entropy_loss(preds,classes[:2])
print mod.test_on_batch(x[:2],classes[:2])[0]
print 100*(mod.test_on_batch(x[:2],classes[:2])[0] / 
replica_cross_entropy_loss(preds,classes[:2]) - 1)
```

What I am doing here is comparing the built-in keras loss to a (I believe) faithful reconstruction using numpy. Now, experimenting with the hidden units in the mlp architecture outlined yields some interesting results. Specifically:

> The keras cost function is systematically higher than the numpy
>   equivalent, with the difference related to the number of neurons in
>   the hidden layer.

As an illustration, here is a simple graph that plots the number of neurons in the hidden layer of this mlp vs the pct overestimate of the keras cost function:

[image]

I should say that this seems to be backend agnostic, effecting both theano and tensorflow.

Judging from this behaviour, it seems likely to be a precision issue. Do you know if there is a way to mitigate this, as for my real model the cost function is consistently 5-10% different to the numpy answer

Comment: I believe the line `x = mod.predict(x[:2])` is a mistake. That makes the comparison basically meaningless and the conclusion makes no sense at all.

Comment: You don't even need a network to compare Keras loss function with its equivalent function in numpy. Just compare the outputs of `replica_cross_entropy_loss(a, b)` and `K.eval(K.mean(K.binary_crossentropy(K.variable(a), K.variable(b))))` for any `a, b`, and you'll find the answer.

Comment: Edited to a more reasonable test, and I still find the same behaviour

Comment: Specifically the two really do converge for a small number of hidden neurons, but grow increasingly further apart for a larger number. Do you  think this is a meaningful comparison?

Comment: You need to remove the regularization since it adds an extra term to the loss returned by `test_on_batch`.

Comment: Of course... thank you!

Comment: If the question is answered, can you summarize the answer. Else, please clarify the remaining questions.

Answer (score 0):

There was a regularisation term difference between the two cost functions, which is arguably not that useful in evaluating performance